# React App | Downloading modules not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies

I made a homepage with several links in it. A tutorial was explaining how to link to another page in your website.

One of the first steps was to download a dependency called

```
sudo npm install --save react-router
```

After typing in the terminal `sudo npm install --save react-router`

It is resulting in a error-message I don't understand.

```
npm WARN react-static-container@1.0.1 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-router@5.0.0 requires a peer of react@>=15 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN create-react-context@0.2.3 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN frank@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I read in the error-message that I have to install peer dependencies myself. It's standing there 3 times. But where to start?

Can you tell my step by step how to manage this error? Reading across React websites it's not clear for me how to solve this issue.

EDIT:
The website works fine.
But now I would like to add a Router (dependency module) to change pages.

I only run into the above error messages by downloading this dependency.

Comment: Does it actually not work subsequently? They're all just warnings.

Comment: Hi Jonrsharpe.
The REACT-App website is just running.
The problem is just that what I see. Apparently I don't have something I need.

So if I clean my code without the Router part the website works.

Comment: So it *is* working? What's the *problem* you're trying to solve? Note you can [edit] your question.

Comment: The website works fine. 
But now I would like to add a Router (dependency module) to change pages.

For example:
import { Link} from './react-router';

I need to download a dependency to manage a Route. 
I only run into the above error messages by downloading this dependency.

This means I can't link a correct page to a link now.

Comment: Again, those are just *warnings*. That's why they say `WARN`. Did the installation *fail*? If you actually try using routing in your app, what happens?

Comment: Oke, my bad! thank you. I must program it first then. I can't test it right now because I don't have programmed it out. I will close this topic for now.

I think you helping me a lot right now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `npm install --save react` before trying to install `react-router`.

Answer (score 0):

Well in v4, react-router exports core components and functions. While react-router-dom exports DOM related components like Link, BrowserRouter, NavLink etc. So it will re-export all of react-router exports. so just install react-router-dom.

```
npm i react-router-dom
```